# Dell TPM what is it and can it be attached to Dell R210 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I read about Dell producing TPMs for their products. What is TPM physically ? Is it module to plug inside the machine or is it like usb hash code generator or is it something else? And do they supply TPMs for their server line (I have Dell R210 with w2008R2) ? What are the costs?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Apparently all Dell R210 servers (or most of them excluding countries like China, Russia, Brazil if I am not mistaken) got TPM chip. That what would be a sensitive answer on my question.

Answer (score 3):

TPM = Trusted Platform Module.

Wikipedia is your friend. I dont feel like stealing from them by copy/pasting the description of a TPM here.

> And do they supply TPMs for their server line (I have Dell R210 with w2008R2) ? What are the 
>   costs?

if ever occured to you that if Dell offers them, Dell can answer this question better? Voting to close.

Comment: you ar every friendly and more important knowledgeable expert in googling.. will use your help on helpwithgoogle.com.. voting to shut you up

Comment: Come on. if it is too hard for you to go to wikipedia and enter "TPM" - then you would not understand an answer here anyway, you know. This is a SIMPLE and VERY LIMITED question - one where it is faster for most people to find an answer than to make a post. Your vote to shut me up is - well, lets say you can vote whatever you want, people waste their time all the time.